# Failed to get location permission for mapbox in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, android-permissions

I'm trying to get the current user location in an android application made by `kotlin` that runs a `mapBox` map.

here is the code am using:

```
    private fun enablingLocation() {
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            locationEngine!!.getLastLocation(object : LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: LocationEngineResult) {
                    val location: Location = result.lastLocation!!
                    if (location != null) {
                        println("the user location is ${mapboxMap!!.locationComponent.lastKnownLocation!!.latitude} ")
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(@NonNull exception: Exception) {
                    // failure
                }
            })
        }else {
            val permissionsManager: PermissionsManager? = null
            permissionsManager!!.requestLocationPermissions(this)

        }
    }
```

But whenever I run the application it gives me an error in the line :

`permissionsManager!!.requestLocationPermissions(this)`

and here is how the error looks like :

[image]

Comment: As you're creating an object of `PermissionManager` class, try `val permissionsManager: PermissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)`.

Comment: Also, You can directly request location permission using `requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), 1)`.